# Cleaning many string variables at once with strip()

Tags: python

I'm trying to get rid of two special character combinations from all my variables with strip.
is there a better way to do this with a loop?

```
currentdisk = currentdisk.strip("└─")
currentdisk = currentdisk.strip("├─")
currentmpath = currentmpath.strip("└─")
currentmpath = currentmpath.strip("├─")
currentpartition = currentpartition.strip("└─")
currentpartition = currentpartition.strip("├─")
volumegroup = volumegroup.strip("└─")
volumegroup = volumegroup.strip("├─")
logicalvolume = logicalvolume.strip("└─")
logicalvolume = logicalvolume.strip("├─")
mountpoint = mountpoint.strip("└─")
mountpoint = mountpoint.strip("├─")
```

Comment: Can you try with combination of `map` and `list comprehension` ?

Comment: It would be a pretty large change to your code base, but can these variables be moved to be key/value pairs in a dictionary instead? Otherwise "Dynamically referencing variables" is something I would not attempt to implement as it's a major anti-pattern (assuming it's even possible).

Comment: I suspect you should remove that stuff **before** you assign to those variables in the first place. But we can't see the code where you do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Group all variables in a dict.
2. Iterate over with your 2 strip operations.
3. Get each variable by key.

```
# 1. fill the dict
my_values = {
    'currentdisk': currentdisk,
    'currentmpath': currentmpath,
    'currentpartition': currentpartition,
    'volumegroup': volumegroup,
    'logicalvolume': logicalvolume,
    'mountpoint': mountpoint
}

# 2. strip
for k in my_values.keys():
    my_values.update({k: my_values[k].strip('└─├─')})

# 3. access a value by key
currentdisk = my_values.get('currentdisk')
```